# React page with PHP as login page

Tags: php, reactjs, authentication

Asking as i was unable to find the answer for two days.

My institution uses PHP for login page and authentication. And im trying to integrate my react app into this.

This is the current model

Login.php

```
<form name="loginform" action="Auth.php" method="post" >
```

Auth.php

```
if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
do the authentication
}

//  if authentication is valid

header ("location :http://myreactpage ") //my react page
```

3. As you are aware now, even though the authentication passes, anyone can access my react page link without going through the php files, as the link is visible in the URL.

What's the best way that my react application can only allow users logged in from that php files. Thank you for your valuable time !.

Comment: How does your PHP code *currently* check if a user is authenticated?  You'd use that same logic in the PHP code which serves the React page, and in any AJAX endpoint invoked by the JavaScript code, just like any other page in the PHP application.  It's not clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: @David it checks when the login.php sends the username and password to auth.php

Comment: And that's all it does?  There's nothing which tracks later requests?  The user is required to send their username and password with every request?  If that's the case then you'd need the user to send their username and password when requesting the page that serves the React application as well.  Though this won't make for a good user experience over time, if the user ever has to go to another page or make AJAX requests.  It sounds like you first need to research how to build authentication/authorization into a PHP application in the first place, React isn't even involved yet.

Comment: You would either need 2 separate apps, one for login and one for logged in users and then serve this login app just as normal with static assets but serve the other app with your PHP app and check if users are authenticated. Another solution would be to serve the app statically including to not authenticated users but deny requests to backend when users are unauthenticated (which you should be doing anyways)